# Does accessing RAM from 2 threads double access time (synchronous access)?

Tags: multithreading, memory, cpu, multiprocessing

As in topic.

If i want to access RAM from 2 different threads, completly different cells in memory, do they queue and are sent asynchronously or queue?

Lets say accessing memory from one thread (roundtrip till i retrieve data to CPU) is 100ns

How long will it take to process 2 of these queries from 2 threads in same time?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possibilities — number of cores, cache hierarchy, implementation particulars that vary across even very similar era CPUs targeted toward different prices & power consumptions.

For one, let's say the two competing threads are time slicing on the same core.  When that's the case, then since they are running on the same core they are competing with each other for the attention of the core's cache, and your cache hit rate could essentially be lower than if you were running one thread at a time.  That being said, it still depends on the loads: if the cache is not thrashing (e.g. the threads only need about half the cache or less), then this effect probably is mitigated.  Depending on the organization of the cache, for example, a direct mapped cache will have more interference (resulting in misses) with different addresses that have the same low bits than a 8-way set associative cache, and this applies whether these accesses come from the same thread or different threads here since they are sharing a core & common cache hierarchy.  However, back to the question, in this scenario, the two threads are time slicing, so only one is running at a time, and that one has full command of the CPU.  There may be queuing in the cache of modern CPU architecture with just a single thread as the processor tries to overlap multiple memory accesses; some of that queuing may overlap with thread switching but in the large, one of the threads is running and the other not, so they are competing for cache space due to the alternation of time slicing, but not really competing directly at the same point in time.

For another, let's say the two competing threads are running in parallel on two different cores.  When that's the case, the two cores will usually have independent top-level caches, which allows them to access independent memory locations each at full speed of that cache.  Usually the two cores will share an L3 (level 3) cache, which is probably where reads and writes to the same address are detected (depending on CPU architecture).  Though as your scenario involves disjoint memory addresses, the two CPUs will probably function more-or-less as if they were running rather separately; though they are sharing some lower cache levels and main memory, so are competing with each other for L3 cache access and space, and misses to main memory.  Here, there is most likely some kind of queuing mechanism in a shared L3 cache that can service both threads queuing requests from either thread as needed.  Ultimately if both threads have an L3 cache miss at the same time, one request will be serviced before the other (due to the limitations of the main memory bus, which probably can only service one cache line at a time); the other is probably queued at some level in the cache hierarchy.

Comment: "Ultimately if both threads have an L3 cache miss at the same time, one request will be serviced before the other (due to the limitations of the main memory bus, which probably can only service one cache line at a time); the other is probably queued at some level in the cache hierarchy." 
It is mainly about this case. So when 2 threads ask, 1 is waiting for the memory bus, and second one is in queue waiting for 1st thread to finish, right? If thats the case, writing memory intensive tasks for multi core systems is very limited, right?

Comment: Yes, this is true, but don't discount the separate L1 & L2 caches that the separate cores have, which allows them some measure of independence.  If these tasks are memory intensive and truly memory independent then giving each its own dedicated computer is probably an upgrade; however, if they are only partially independent and would have to use networking or other to communicate, the situation is far less clear.

Comment: About separate DRAM channels - for example threadrippers as i saw have 4. As i understand they work separately, so in such case threads should be able to execute in parallel, right?

Comment: It is possible; I don't know about those.  On some processors, the separate DRAM channels are used to interleave memory so to decrease the access time of a full cache line rather than fetch independent cache lines.